# How to show information in status bar on android when app is in background

Tags: android, background, statusbar

guys
I have an android app and I want to develop a feature which shows app running time in android status bar when android app is in background. This is similar to the in call status that shows the length of the current call on top of screen and allow user to touch it go back to the call screen.

Is there a way to doing this?

Thanks in advance!
Alex

Comment: Create a `OnGoingNotification`

Comment: Thanks Syed. So call status on top of screen is OnGoingNotification? when app is killed and this OnGoingNotification will disappear? if App is alive and it always shows there?

Comment: Yes thats it. its that easy...